# Error: IFS expects all arguments after position 0 to come in pairs

Tags: google-sheets, syntax, google-sheets-formula, ifs

I'm trying to reference a cell depending on the value of A2, but when I use the following code, I get an #N/A error. My google is not in English, so I don't know the exact translation, but it's something about the IFS function wanting all arguments after position 0 to come in pairs.

This is what the code looks like currently.

```
=IFS(
$A2="[Greater Flask of the Vast Horizon]"; G2;
$A2="[Greater Flask of the Undertow]"; G3;
$A2="[Greater Flask of Endless Fathoms]"; G4;
$A2="[Greater Flask of the Currents]"; G5;
$A2="[Potion of Empowered Proximity]"; G6;
$A2="[Potion of Focused Resolve]"; G7;
$A2="[Superior Battle Potion of Intellect]"; G8;
$A2="[Superior Battle Potion of Agility]"; G9;
$A2="[Superior Battle Potion of Strength]"; G10;
$A2="[Superior Battle Potion of Stamina]"; G11;
$A2="[Potion of Unbridled Fury]"; G12;
$A2="[Superior Steelskin Potion]"; G13;
$A2="[Potion of Wild Mending]"; G14;
$A2="[Abyssal Healing Potion]"; G15;
)
```

What should I change to make it work like intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the comma/semicolon after `G15`:

```
=IFS(
 $A2="[Greater Flask of the Vast Horizon]";   G2;
 $A2="[Greater Flask of the Undertow]";       G3;
 $A2="[Greater Flask of Endless Fathoms]";    G4;
 $A2="[Greater Flask of the Currents]";       G5;
 $A2="[Potion of Empowered Proximity]";       G6;
 $A2="[Potion of Focused Resolve]";           G7;
 $A2="[Superior Battle Potion of Intellect]"; G8;
 $A2="[Superior Battle Potion of Agility]";   G9;
 $A2="[Superior Battle Potion of Strength]";  G10;
 $A2="[Superior Battle Potion of Stamina]";   G11;
 $A2="[Potion of Unbridled Fury]";            G12;
 $A2="[Superior Steelskin Potion]";           G13;
 $A2="[Potion of Wild Mending]";              G14;
 $A2="[Abyssal Healing Potion]";              G15)
```

Comment: I had not realized it would affect the code, but removing it worked. Thank you!